# How to loop through .txt file links on website, scrape, and store in one malleable csv/excel file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to be able to scrape the data from a particular website (https://physionet.org/challenge/2012/set-a/) and the subdirectories like it, while also taking each text file and adding it to a giant csv or excel file so that I might be able to see all the data in one place.

I have deployed the following code, similar to [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-web-scrape-with-python-in-4-minutes-bc49186a8460), but my code basically downloads all the text files on the page, and stores them in my working directory. And, it honestly just takes too long to run.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://physionet.org/challenge/2012/set-a/'
response = requests.get(url)
response # 200 indicates that it works...

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

for i in range(5,len(soup.findAll('a'))+1): #'a' tags are for links
    one_a_tag = soup.findAll('a')[i]
    link = one_a_tag['href']
    download_url = 'https://physionet.org/challenge/2012/set-a/'+ link
 urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url,'./'+link[link.find('/132539.txt')+1:]) 
    time.sleep(1) #pause the code for a sec
```

Actual results are just a bunch of text files crowding my working directory, but before the for loop stops, I'd like to put it in one large csv file format.

Comment: Personally I would use pandas `pd.read_html(download_url)` to create dataframes and `concat()` them together one after another, then you can work with the data or write the final dataframe `to_csv(filename)`. You could also do something similar by opening a file in append mode and just adding each file to it with the `csv` module

Comment: `pd.read_html` requires tables to be present

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save them, but have to do it a bit at a time (maybe you don't have enough RAM to hold everything in at once), then I would just append the files to a master file one by one.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

output_file = 'outputfile.txt'
url = 'https://physionet.org/challenge/2012/set-a/'

# Download and find all the links. Check the last 4 characters to verify it's one
# of the files we are looking for
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a') if a['href'][-4:] == '.txt']

# Clear the current file
with open(output_file, 'w'):
    pass

# Iterate through all the links
for href in links:

    response = requests.get("{}{}".format(url, href), verify=False)

    if response:
        # Open up the output_file in append mode so we can just write to the one file
        with open(output_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(response.text)
            print(len(response.text.split('\n')))
```

The one downside to this is that you would have the headers from each text file. but you can change the `f.write()` to the following and get it without any headers

```
f.write("\n".join(response.text.split('\n')[1:]))
```

If you do have the available RAM, you could read in all the files using a list comprehension then use `pandas.concat()` to put them in one giant dataframe. Then use `df.to_csv()` to export it to a file.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv("{}{}".format(url, href)) for href in links])
df.to_csv(output_file)
```

Comment: Thanks Brian! I'm getting the following after doing the request in your code:

`C:\Users\mcphersonkp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)`

Comment: is it preventing your code from running or just annoying to see it pop up? If it's just annoying, then I added two more lines that should suppress that

Comment: If I were to change to making each individual file it's own output file, would I just take out the `[1:]` in the `f.write`?

Comment: It's just annoying. Ideally when I'm done, I'd like to have a smooth running Jupyter notebook. I'll add the lines!

Comment: the `[1:]` just strips off the header row. You can store each file individually by altering the `output_file` and setting it to `href`. At that point, you can just use `f.read()`. But then you have a "bunch of text files crowding [your] working directory"